# Create not saving record due to non-existent field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Can't figure this out. I'm running Postgres on a Ruby app and my schema looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180518200146) do
  create_table "amazons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "auth_token"
    t.text "marketplace"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "shop_id"
    t.boolean "three_speed"
    t.text "seller_id"
    t.string "shipping_countries", array: true
  end

  create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "shopify_domain", null: false
    t.string "shopify_token", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "paid", default: false
    t.boolean "setup", default: false
    t.string "carrier_id"
    t.index ["shopify_domain"], name: "index_shops_on_shopify_domain", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "amazons", "shops"
end
```

I did remove `shopify_domain` from the `Amazons` table. But I ran that migration and as you can see in my schema its gone.

However I try and `create` a new record and I get this error message:
`NoMethodError (undefined method shopify_domain for #<Amazon:0x000000041fb9c8>`

I'm creating the new `Amazon` record, by scoping it to the shop like this:

```
current_shop.amazons.create(
  marketplace: marketplace,
  seller_id: seller_id,
  auth_token: auth_token,
  shipping_countries: countries,
  shop_id: current_shop.id)
```

With `current_shop` being a method that gets the current shop from the session. It works fine.

Where did I go astray?

EDIT: I went and checked PG to be sure, and the field isn't their either. Here is what PG has:

```
 id                 | bigint                      | not null default nextval('amazons_id_seq'::regclass)
 auth_token         | text                        | 
 marketplace        | text                        | 
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 shop_id            | integer                     | 
 three_speed        | boolean                     | 
 seller_id          | text                        | 
 shipping_countries | character varying[]         |
```

EDIT: Here is the `Amazon` model

```
class Amazon < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ShopifyApp::SessionStorage
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

And then this is the entire error message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `shopify_domain' for #
<Amazon:0x000000041fb9c8>
Did you mean?  shop_id_change):

app/controllers/concerns/amazon_creds_concern.rb:55:in `save_amazon_creds'
app/controllers/concerns/amazon_creds_concern.rb:23:in `create_amazon_client'
app/controllers/amazon_creds_controller.rb:9:in `amazon_credentials_check'
```

And then the lines of code that match the error message, starting from the bottom up: `app/controllers/amazon_creds_controller.rb:9:in amazon_credentials_check`

```
render json: {amazon_creds_status: create_amazon_client(marketplace, seller_id, auth_token, countries), countries: countries.blank?}
```

Then `app/controllers/concerns/amazon_creds_concern.rb:23:in`

```
save_amazon_creds(marketplace, seller_id, auth_token, countries)
```

Finally `app/controllers/concerns/amazon_creds_concern.rb:55:in`

```
current_shop.amazons.create(
  marketplace: marketplace,
  seller_id: seller_id,
  auth_token: auth_token,
  shipping_countries: countries,
  shop_id: current_shop.id)
```

Comment: Please, show your `Amazon` model. There is a possibility, you use somewhere `shopify_domain`.

Comment: It *might* help if you show the actual error stack and the code where the line is raised.

Comment: sure thing, I updated the post with more info

Comment: I guess one of those methods in `amazon_creds_concern` is throwing the error. If I were you, I think I would do a `puts current_shop.amazons`, `puts marketplace`, `puts seller_id`, etc. right before that `current_shop.amazons.create` call and see which is the culprit. To save yourself some typing, you could add them one by one until you find out which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include ShopifyApp::SessionStorage
```

adds

```
validates :shopify_domain, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

to your Amazon class.

You either need the shopify_domain in that class (or use a forward) or you need to remove the include from the Amazon class.

Same for `shopify_token` by the way.

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/master/lib/shopify_app/session/session_storage.rb

Comment: Wahoo!! thank you so much, who knows how long that would have taken!